# When does a '3 month' period in a membership status actually roll over

Tags: civimember

Wondering how civi calculates 3 months, given that month lengths vary, eg they could be between 89 to 92 days (I think).

I am asking because we have End Date March 31, and then Grace for 3 months. Here, in NZ, it is July 1, but Grace members are still showing Grace, and not clear if something has failed (yes scheduled job is enabled and running and no log errors), or if the 'calculation' of 3 months might be a bit stretchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calculation of **next** or **past 3 months** was decidedly dodgy for relative dates in searches (which is why these have been replaced with 90-day intervals in v4.7). The same method may apply for the membership status update.

If I remember correctly, it calulates the number of days in three calendar months starting with the current month.

So I think you may find that for an end date of March 31, CiviCRM will change the status after 31(March) + 30 (April) + 31(May) = 92 days, which should be 2 July.

Comment: Bang on, thank you. I can reset to 91 days in there case.